# NDSolve::ndnum encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at

Tags: differential-equations

I have a problem and I hope someone of you can help me. I want to solve a rather complicated PDE via NDSolve but it keeps telling me 
NDSolve::ndnum: Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at t == 1.`.

I can't relly figure out why. Maybe someone of you can help me.

I tried the following code:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
T = 1;
sigma = 1;
K = 10;
rho = 0.5;
gamma = 1;
mu = 1;
a = 1;

sol = NDSolve[{D[p[t,y,s],t] + 0.5 * sigma^2 * y * s^2 * D[p[t,y,s],{s,2}]+ a*D[p[t,y,s],y] + 0.5 * D[p[t,y,s],{y,2}]* y + sigma * y * rho * s * D[p[t,y,s],y,s] - ((1-rho^2) * y * D[p[t,y,s],y] + (mu * rho) / sigma) * D[p[t,y,s],y] + 0.5 * gamma*(1-rho^2) * y * D[p[t,y,s],y]^2 == 0, p[T,y,s] == Max(s-K)}, p , {t, 0 , 1}, {y,0.1,10}, {s, 10, 100} ]
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: What exactly were you trying to do with `Max(s-K)`?

Comment: Do you have any initial conditions in there?

Comment: Oh, damn. That's embarrassing. I meant Max[s-K,0]. It seems to work now if I add some more boundary conditions. Thank you very much for pointing that out!